# Category now showing on backend

Tags: magento-1.9, category, cache, reindex

I have a category that is showing on the frontend of my website, but that I can't find anywhere on my backend, not even in specific store views. How is this possible? I want to turn the category off.

I already tried reindexing and emptying my cache.

Comment: did you checked under both `Manage products` & `Manage categories` section ?

Comment: Yes I did. The category doesn't appear under either one of them

Comment: May be your locale change the name of category

Comment: What do you mean @MurtuzaZabuawala ?